# I have just bought the King Products Joomla LMS component - Professional version. How can I change the front end style?

Tags: joomla-extensions

The front end of the Joomla LMS component from King Products is supposed to allow me to change the style that is used in the front end of the site.
However, I am unable to find how change it.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Joomla LMS is one of the best choices, it has far more features than any other on the market. In the admin section of the component, if using Joomla 2.5 OR 3+ click options.
you will be taken to the component config page.
There are three tabs. 
On the LMS King main preferences tab, you will see the option "Template Style"
These are for the front end style. I like the "guru" style the best.

While you're there, you can set the admin styles too in the "Admin Color" option. I like the "Modern excellence" style.

Good Luck.